# How to strip down JVM to get the smallest install possible?

Tags: java, jvm, installation

I have a Java app to deploy and want to deploy the JVM along with it (to simplify install). I want to have the JVM stripped down to only include the pieces the app needs to keep the distributable small. How can I strip down the JVM to bring the size down? Can this be done with the [Java Kernel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/6u10faq.jsp#JKernel) or is there some alternative to the Sun JVM that is a much smaller install? My target platform is Windows.

Comment: The Java kernel seems like what you are looking for. But why not just depend on a standard JVM install ? Its bundled  and maintained by someone else; why over-complicate things ?

Comment: Mostly because the app itself is really small and I don't want an 85+ MB JVM to run it. Maybe I should have used something other than Java...

Comment: Convert your code to C# and users will have to install 400+ MB .net Framework.

Comment: where do you get your numbers from?. The full JVM (without the JDK) for windows is 15.90 MB, the Java Kernel is 680 KB.

Comment: On my machine C:\Program Files\java\jre6 is more than 85MB in size.

Comment: That's the uncompressed size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirements are mixed up: deploying the JVM with an app simplifies *your* job because you don't have to worry about JVM versions - but can be a considerable annoyance to users who don't want to have dozens of JVMs installed just to make programmers' jobs easier. Shouldn't you worry about that just as much as about distribution sizes?

I'd say that the best you can do is to use the [Deployment Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) JavaScript to deploy your application via Java WebStart and specify a Java Kernel install. This makes sure a new JVM is installed only when actually required. The rest of the time it doesn't have to install anything except your app - the best possible case.

Comment: It's more so that for people, say like my mom, who wont understand why the program they're trying to install is asking for this Java thing. If I can use something very small for the included JVM, then I don't have to worry about users having to try to manage the app + JVM install.

Comment: I don't see how the size has anything to do with the ease of installation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three ideas:

- Use [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) to compile your application to machine code, then add what parts of the [classpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/) that you need.
- Download [Kaffe](http://www.kaffe.org/), and strip out parts that you don't need.
- Grab the [Java source code](http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/), and strip out parts that you don't need.

Good luck.